# Height and Width of a Farseer body?

Tags: c#, xna, farseer

I have a body named PersonA. If PersonA collides with another body, the width and height of that body should be saved. I tried it like this but I always get error messages that "Width" and "Height" don't exist.

```
 bool PersonA_OnCollision(Fixture fixtureA, Fixture fixtureB, FarseerPhysics.Dynamics.Contacts.Contact contact)
 {
    //How tall and broad is the body that collided with PersonA 
    float Width = fixtureB.Body.Width;
    float Height = fixtureB.Body.Height;

    return true;
 }
```

What is wrong? How can I get the width and height of another body?

Comment: I haven't used Farseer in a while but from memory a Body only keeps track of position. You need to get the Shape attached to the fixture I think. The descriptions at the top of the documentation are a good place to start.. https://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/documentation

Answer (score 0):

try thiis! =}

i have not tested iey but i think it works fine.

```
class GameBody
{
    public Body body;
    public Vector2 position;
    public int width;
    public int height;

    public GameBody(int width, int height, int x, int y, BodyType bodyType)
    {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        body = BodyFactory.CreateRectangle(Game1.world, ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits((float)width), ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits((float)height), 1f);
        body.BodyType = bodyType;
        body.FixedRotation = false;
        body.SleepingAllowed = true;
        body.LinearDamping = 1f;
        body.AngularDamping = 2f;
        setPosition(x, y);

        body.UserData = this;

        body.OnCollision += gameBody_OnCollision;
    }

    public void setPosition(float x, float y)
    {
        position.X = x;
        position.Y = y;
        body.SetTransform(new Vector2(ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(x), ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(y)), 0);
    }

    bool gameBody_OnCollision(Fixture me, Fixture him, Contact contact)
    {
        float Width = (him.Body.UserData as GameBody).width;
        float Height = (him.Body.UserData as GameBody).height;

        return true;
    }

}
```